# How to get the indices of the important regions from heatmaps in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am having a problem in extracting the indices of the important regions as shown in the heatmap. The data here is one dimensional in shape. Basically, for the below heatmap I want indices of the three segments (as shown in red). I am actually expecting if there is some attribute of the variable t that can help in getting those indices. I don't want to do approaches like peak detection and all on the c variable.

```
plt.plot(numpy_mat[0, :, 0].squeeze())
t = plt.scatter(np.arange(length_ts), numpy_mat[0, :, 0].squeeze(), cmap='jet', c=cam, s=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is inside your `cam` array, not in your plot. You need something like `redlikes = np.argwhere(cam > threshold)` to get the indices of the "red-like" zone. Then you can use `numpy_mat[0, redlikes, 0]` to extract them. Similarly, `np.argwhere(np.diff(cam>threshold)==1)` would give the indices of the starts. (Also note that 'jet' has a horrible reputation in highlighting arbitrary regions in yellow)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks a lot. Where can I get the value of the threshold?

Comment: You need to choose one. There is no strict place where the "red-like" starts.  For example `threshold = 0.1*cam.min() + 0.9*cam.max()`